# View to ViewModel to Settings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, application-settings

Is it possible to refactor the currentDevices into a collection?
Basically, I have three comboboxes in which the selectedvalue is bound to currentDevices. then the currentDevices are taken from a settings file.

View

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding availableDevices}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding currentDevice1}">
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding availableDevices}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding currentDevice2}">
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding availableDevices}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding currentDevice3}">
</ComboBox>
```

ViewModel

```
public string currentDevice1 {
    get
    {
        return SampleSettings.Default.Device1;
    }
    set
    {
        SampleSettings.Default.Device1 = value;
    }

}
public string currentDevice2
{
    get
    {
        return SampleSettings.Default.Device2;
    }
    set
    {
        SampleSettings.Default.Device2 = value;
    }
}
public string currentDevice3
{
    get
    {
        return SampleSettings.Default.Device3;
    }
    set
    {
        SampleSettings.Default.Device3 = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there always ever three devices?  Probably not worth it.  Apart from it not being CamelCased, the names are also terrible.  I'll just sit here assuming you renamed them for the purposes of asking this question.

Comment: no, there will be a variable number of devices. and i also renamed them for simplicity.

Comment: Then Ed's answer below is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write a `DeviceOptionViewModel`, and give the main viewmodel an ObservableCollection.

DeviceOptionViewModel.cs

```
public class DeviceOptionViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _currentDevice;
    public String CurrentDevice {
        get { return _currentDevice; }
        set { 
            _currentDevice = value; 
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, 
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentDevice));
        }
    }

    //  Parent event assigns this to his own availableDevices
    //  when he creates this.
    public IEnumerable AvailableDevices { get; set; }
}
```

Main VM:

```
    public ObservableCollection<DeviceOptionViewModel> 
        CurrentDevices { get; private set; }
            = new ObservableCollection<DeviceOptionViewModel>();
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentDevices}"
    >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- DataContext here is DeviceOptionViewModel. We gave it its 
                 own reference to AvailableDevices to simplify binding. -->
            <ComboBox 
                ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableDevices}"
                SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentDevice}"
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Back to main viewmodel:

```
protected void PopulateCurrentDevices(IEnumerable<String> stringsFromWherever)
{
    CurrentDevices.Clear();

    foreach (var device in stringsFromWherever)
    {
        var dovm = new DeviceOptionViewModel() {
                CurrentDevice = device,
                AvailableDevices = this.availableDevices
            };

        dovm.PropertyChanged += DeviceOptionViewModel_PropertyChangedHandler;

        CurrentDevices.Add(dovm);
    }
}

protected void DeviceOptionViewModel_PropertyChangedHandler(object sender, 
     PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var dopt = sender as DeviceOptionViewModel;

    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(DeviceOptionViewModel.CurrentDevice))
    {
        //  Do stuff
    }
}
```

So you populate and repopulate `CurrentDevices` in your viewmodel as needed, and the UI will magically appear if all the notifications are done correctly.

If you create a new `ObservableCollection` and assign that to the `CurrentDevices` property, you'll need to raise `PropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentDevices))` on the main viewmodel. I made the setter private to avoid having to implement that detail. If it's not a huge collection, may as well just `Clear()` and `Add()` on the same old instance.

Comment: @PaoloGo My pleasure!